# Masstransit reconnection policy when RabbitMQ is down

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have the following different scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

> RabbitMQ is up.
>
> Consumer starts and subscribes correctly through MassTransit to RabbitMQ.
>
> RabbitMQ goes down.
>
> RabbitMQ goes up again.
>
> If Consumer tried to subscribe with **busControl.StartAsync();** then it won't reconnect anymore
>
> If Consumer tried to subscribe with **busControl.Start();** then it will correctly reconnect.

Already find this a bit weird.. but okey.

**Scenario 2**

> RabbitMQ is down
>
> Consumer goes up and tries to subscribe with **busControl.Start();**, which will fail due to RabbitMQ down
>
> RabbitMQ goes up
>
> Consumer is not able to reconnect to RabbitMQ

But I need this case to be covered somehow..

Registration:

```
private static void RegisterRabbitMQ(SimpleInjectorContainer container)
{
    container.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.AddBus(() => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQHostName"), hostConfigurator =>
            {
#if !DEBUG
                hostConfigurator.Username(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQUsername"));
                hostConfigurator.Password(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQPassword"));

                hostConfigurator.UseCluster(c =>
                {
                    string[] hostnames = ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitMQNodes").Split(';');
                    c.ClusterMembers = hostnames;
                });
#endif
            });
        }));
    });
}
```

Starting bus:

```
try
{
    RegisterRabbitMQ(container);
    var busControl = container.GetInstance<IBusControl>();
    busControl.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Seq.Error("RabbitMQ broker is not reachable, BusControl cannot be started. ", ex);
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We've been using Mass Transit in production for quite some time now. Once Mass Transit connects to Rabbit the connection management of mass transit is really solid. It is the starting and stopping of VM's /Containers and rabbit being down when your consumer services come up is the real problem i believe.

The way we approached this issue is to move the starting of a consumer onto a different thread of the service and implement a retry operation. This will allow your service to start successfully and to go into an loop and wait until rabbit comes up. Importantly we log that the service cannot connect to rabbit, so we have visibility of that.

code

```
private async Task StartAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {

        bool isConnected = false;
        while(!isConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceBus = CreateServiceBus();
                ServiceBus?.Start();
                isConnected = true;
                _loggingService.Info("Messaging service bus started.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _loggingService.Error("Cannot connect to message broker host.", ex);
                Thread.Sleep(Defined_Time);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

then to configure your bus is exactly as you see in the demo's

```
private IBusControl CreateServiceBus()
{
    var url = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "rabbitmq://{0}", _messagingServerName);
    var uri = new Uri(url);

   _loggingService.DebugFormat("Starting messaging service bus: \"{0}\". Username=\"{1}\".", url, _messagingUsername);

    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
    {
        Host = sbc.Host(uri, h =>
        {
            h.Username(_messagingUsername);
            h.Password(_messagingPassword);
        });

        //Configure end points
    });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It works! But I cannot figure out the meaning of `ServiceBus?.Start()` ... If `CreateServiceBus()` returns null, why should I say that the bus is started ?

Comment: @selganor yeah that shouldn't have a null coalesce cause will trick it into believe it's connected when it hasn't.